# OpenShift (Apache AAA proxy and Jenkins)

Tags: apache, url, redirect, jenkins, openshift

I have an OpenShift environment built with an Apache AAA Pod (service and route) that allows external (to OpenShift) https requests via an intranet browser (yes, I mean intranet and not internet). Apache is setup as a proxy server for multiple pods/services inside of OpenShift. I also have a new pod that was recently created that runs Jenkins. Jenkins has a web interface built in. I am able to get to the Jenkins web GUI by setting up a ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse for the default Jenkins web address.

Now here comes the problem...

When I go to example.com/jenkins, Apache sees the request and passes it to the Jenkins Pod but the Pod returns another address example.com/login. For this I have to enter another ProxyPass and Reverse into Apache. I then get that in and find that every link on the presented Jenkins Web GUI has another link that seems to present https://example.com/*. This is a problem because there are dozens of sub links and sub pages that each seem to require a separate ProxyPass and Reverse entry.

To add to this, I cannot simply pass "/" to the Jenkins pod because there are other pods and services that are being passed through the Apache server. My department does not have access to create new URLs on a whim so I have to stick with example.com/ as my only path into my OpenShift setup.

How can I do one of the following:

1. Change Jenkins to force the presented URL to include a header for every link. Like putting .../jenkins/* in front of every link so that I can use .../jenkins/ as my ProxyPass & Reverse to cover all jenkins web GUI URLs.
2. Configure Apache to convert the URLs coming from the Jenkins Pod into a URL that is presented to the web browser in such a way that .../jenkins/ is added between  & /login or any other jenkins web links.
3. Some other option that I have not thought of yet that may have worked for others with similar setups.

(Sorry for the long question but there are a lot of details that needed to be included as this is a complex issue.)

Answer (score 0):

You could startup jenkins at a different context path: `java -jar jenkins.war --prefix=/jenkins`, or start it up behind tomcat with a different context path.

Have you set the Jenkins URL in the Jenkins->Manage Jenkins->Configure System?

Comment: I have tried the --prefix and tried changing the "Jenkins URL" options on the web interface. The --prefix didn't seem to do anything and further research suggested that the "Jenkins URL" options are for message links. Like when an admin subscribes to an alert, Jenkins uses that "Jenkins URL" as a means to get the user back to the Jenkins instance. This is in place to make the message links compatible with proxies.

Comment: I tested the --prefix, and it worked as advertised. Jenkins was now at localhost:8080/jenkins instead of at the root.

Comment: Ok so...I go from Chrome:https://example.com/jenkins -> Routers & DNS Cloud -> OpenShift Route listening for https://example.com -> OpenShift Apache Service -> Apache pod -> Apache listening for /jenkins via ProxyPass and forwarding to localhost:8080/jenkins -> Openshift Jenkins Service -> Jenkins Pod with --prefix=/jenkins configured ....

I am then returned https://example.com/login in my web browser but the page will not display. I then have to manually enter "/jenkins" between the .com and /login for it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Others appear to have the same issue:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/irN9N7Zg3jA

Though setting up my ProxyPass, ProxyPassReverse, and --Prefix didn't fix the problem like the "solution" says in the google group.

Comment: I ended up just making the root "/" of my website so that it is used by Jenkins in the Apache proxy configuration. This fixed the majority of the issues but now presents a new issue of some of the sub links being served up on http rather than https. When that happens the site doesn't display in the browser. ...guess I'm just running from one wall to the next...

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this in two steps

1. implement the route changes at proxy level
2. implement the route changes at app level

I have implemented the same with Openshift environment.
Thanks.